# How to count lines in unix with particular string

Tags: unix

I have a file like below.

```
Name1 IM123
Name2 IM145
Name1 IM901
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of the name.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`$ grep "Name" test.txt | wc -l`</strike>

As @kojiro nicely pointed out `wc` is not needed.

```
$ grep --count "Name" test.txt
```

See [`man wc`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/wc1.html) and [`man grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

For specifically Name1:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /Name1/ {++c} END {print c}' FS=" " file_name.txt
```

For all names:

```
$ awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j,"("count[j]" times)"}' FS=" " file_name.txt
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. =) Make sure to accept any correct answer in order to close down questions for other users.